# Order of eigenvectors when you calculating Jordan matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I've got a question regarding Jordan matrices, more specifically does it matter which order you put eigenvectors in matrix $V$ in $J=V^{-1}AV$?

Can someone intuitively explain how it matter, if it does?

In my example I have matrix

$$A= \begin{bmatrix}
4 & 1 & 1 \\
-2 & 1 & -2 \\
1 & 1 & 4 
\end{bmatrix}  $$

from which I have gotten eigenvectors $$\vec{v_1}=(1,-2,1)$$ $$\vec{v_2}=(0,1,-1)$$

And from which $\vec{v_1}$ I have received a generalized eigenvector $$\vec{v_1}^{(1)}=(1,0,0)$$

So my question is, does it matter, and if so, why does it matter which order I put there eigenvectors in my matrix $V$?